# Question regarding the iPhone In App Purchase capabilities

Tags: iphone, plist, in-app-purchase

I am working on releasing an app that will greatly benefit from using the in app purchase model. The app is a sort of book viewer, and the content I would like to make available for purchase will be more books in various languages. Each book is stored in sqlite format, in separate .db files. Now, the way that my developer has set it all up is that he added a line onto the bottom of the info.plist file called databases. Inside that database section, I can type in 'es' as the key, and for the value the name of the spanish database, and it populates in a uitableview in spanish, using NSLocale. So it is *very* easy to setup and implement different databases, which is great, but now I am confused about how I can implement my in app purchase model. Sorry about the long winded intro, here is my question: Is it possible to have an in app purchase add a line to my info.plist file? Or if not, is it possible to have the purchase reveal a new and updated plist file altogether that I would have already setup correctly? Any help here would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not edit you're info.plist file dynamically.  When you submit your app to The App Store, your app bundle, which includes info.plist, can't change because the signature created when you compile you app is based on the bundle.

You can have an in-app purchase do whatever you want.  You could have the data already stored in the app and just unlock it with an in-app purchase, or you can have the app download the new data in plist format or any other format you want.  Services like [ilime](http://ilime.com) and [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com) make this really easy for you.